# Use two monitors and work on my laptop remote desktop style, but with full resolution

Tags: laptop, multiple-monitors, remote-desktop, resolution

I run Linux Mint on both my desktop workstation, which has 2 large monitors, and on my laptop, which has a 13 inch screen.

I would like to start a remote-desktop session from my desktop, and access my laptop, but have the laptop make full use of the 2 large monitors. Basically I'd like to be able to get the same effect as if I added a second display card to my laptop and plugged in the keyboard, mouse, and two monitors from my desktop directly into the laptop. But I'd like to be able to do this quickly, using software tools, rather than by physically swapping monitors etc. between devices.

I have experimented with TeamViewer, but it only allows a display that is as large as the max resolution of my laptop---1366x768.

Is this possible? Thanks.